# conditions after using strtok()

Tags: c, string

I'm new to C and i would like to learn something that is troubling me.
I have a code where i used strtok and basically it gets a string with the `_#_` and seperates it from the string leaving the rest into chars and ints(i used atoi for that)
The program runs fine when i enter something like that: `hello_#_2001_#_name_#_HARRY` it gives me back hello,2001,name and HARRY. But when I input only hello_#_ it continues to run though stops doing anything. I think i need to assign a certain pointer to the first NULL but not sure if what i think is correct could you please help?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 char *split(char words[99])
 {
  int i;
char *word=strtok(words, "_#_");
char *year=strtok(NULL, "_#_");;  // assigning NULL for previousely where it left off
char *definition=strtok(NULL,"_#_");
char *synonyms=strtok(NULL,"_#_");

i=atoi(year);


printf("%s\n", word);
printf("%i\n",i);
printf("%s\n", definition);
printf("%s\n", synonyms);
return 0;
 }

 int main()
 {
char words[100];
printf("Enter a string\n");
scanf("%s", words);
split(words);
 }
```

Comment: What is exacly the question? Or What is the Problem you are facing? [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) retuns `NULL`when there are no more token. And you don't assign a pointer to `NULL`, it's the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your program and enter the string `hello_#_`, it throws a segfault when `atoi` is called. This is expected since `year`, `definition`, and `synonyms` will all be `NULL`. So you should check `year` for a `NULL` value before calling `atoi`.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> The strtok() and strtok_r() functions return a pointer to the beginning of each subsequent token in the string, after replacing the token itself with a NUL character.  **When no more tokens remain, a null pointer is returned.**

Try checking if the return value of `strtok()` is `NULL` before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some error checking.  If you run out of tokens, strtok returns `NULL`, and then if you try to actually do something with that non-existing string (like pass it to atoi or try to print it) Bad Things will happen.  It's up to you to decide what your function should do in that case (abort? Print what it can?) but you'll have to do something.